# Is Call Stack / Stack Frame Debugging Available for Flutter Web?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, debugging, web, stack

When debugging the Android build, I can get the call stack / stack frames to show up in Flutter DevTools and Android Studio's debug tab.

However, if the target is Flutter Web, then the stack will not show up in either DevlTools or Android Studio - but Flutter Inspector still works in both.

In the attached pic: we see that the execution has paused at a break point in Android Studio because the "step over..." buttons are enabled. However, the "Frames" window is still empty and shows "frames not available". Same thing with DevTools.

[image: android-studio]
[image: flutter-devtools]

My question is: Does Flutter Web support the ability to view the call stack via debuggers?

Documentation seems to suggest that it should be possible...not sure if I missed something.

Version: Flutter 2.10.4 (2022-03-25)

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/101224

Looks like this is an issue with the latest Chrome update (100.0.4896.75). Just so happens that this is the first time I tried to use debugger w/ Flutter Web, so I just assumed that it never worked to start with. I will either downgrade my Chrome or wait for an an official update.